# What does the action: 'raw' means in Faraday in MediawikiApi?

Tags: faraday

In [Class: MediawikiApi::Client](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mediawiki_api/0.5.0/MediawikiApi/Client), there is a method called [get_wikitext](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mediawiki_api/0.5.0/MediawikiApi%2FClient:get_wikitext). Looking at the source code of the method, I see

```
def get_wikitext(title)
  @conn.get '/w/index.php', action: 'raw', title: title
end
```

It seems to be using Faraday gem so I look in the [Faraday code base](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) but cannot find the `get` method of Faraday::Connection and understand.

Can someone explain

1) what this method does, what each part of this method means and how it works?

Especially:

2) What does the `'raw'` in `action: 'raw'` means?

3) Why do we have '/w/' and why index page? is /w/index.php a convention? Does index page meant to include certain things and that's why this method always points to /w/index.php? If it is can you briefly explain it or point me to a source that explains it? What if the wiki I am going to use don't have /w/index.php and only have /index.php? What do I do in this case?

Thank in advanced.

Comment: To answer some of my own questions. I don't know what raw mean, maybe it means raw data. The '/w/' and index url are probably just convention used in wikipedia url and they just hard code that in the wiki API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All http verbs methods are generated dynamically in Faraday, you can find the definition of `get` [here](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L135):

```
%w[get head delete].each do |method|
  class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def #{method}(url = nil, params = nil, headers = nil)
      run_request(:#{method}, url, nil, headers) { |request|
        request.params.update(params) if params
        yield(request) if block_given?
      }
    end
  RUBY
end
```

The signature is `def get(url = nil, params = nil, headers = nil)`, so in your case `action: 'raw', title: title` is the Hash of parameters.
Since this is a GET request, parameters are added to the URL, so the gem is calling `GET .../w/index.php?action=raw&title=title`.